# Angular - Returning data from GraphQL

Tags: html, angular, rxjs, graphql, apollo

So, I'm having an issue while working with Angular. I need to get some user data stored in graphcool so I can work with name (string) and balance (number), but it's only working when I call `userName` and `userBalance` in HTML, not in TS, here's my TS component:

```
public userName: Observable<string>;
public userBalance: Observable<number>;

public getUserById: string;

constructor(
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  private userService: UserService
) {
  this.getUserId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['userId'];
  this.userName = this.userService.getUserById(this.getUserId)
    .pipe(map(res => res[0].name));
  this.userBalance = this.userService.getUserById(this.getUserId)
    .pipe(map(res => res[0].balance));
}
```

And this is the method `getUserById()` in UserService.ts:

```
getUserById(userId: string): Observable<User[]> {
  return apollo
    .query<AllUsersQuery>({
      query: SINGLE_USER_QUERY,
      variables: {
        userId
      }
    }).pipe(
        map(res => res.data.allUsers)
    );
}
```

Whenever I try to print `userName` and `userBalance` into console, it returns an `Observable` instead of a string and a number. But, in HTML, this works well:

```
<div>Name: 
  <p>{{ userName | async }}</p>
</div>
<div>Balance:
  <p>$ {{ userBalance | async }}</p>
</div>
```

I guess it has something to do with async. How can I return the same values as I get in my HTML to my TS background?

*I think it's also important to point that I tried using `.subscribe` instead of `.map` and I could see the actual values on console, but, outside that subscription the values didn't show.*

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Your `userName` and `userBalance` variables are indeed `Observable`s, which is why you see them as such when you log them to the console in your TypeScript. The `async` pipe in your template is taking care of subscribing to the `Observable` for you and is why you are seeing the value there instead of the `Observable`. What are you trying to do in your TypeScript file with those values? Knowing that can help to give you some code on how to handle this.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I'm just at the beginning of this project, but I assume in the future I'm going to need `userBalance` value to apply some math, update this value then send it back to database. That's why I'm looking for an easy way to get this value not just in this component, but wherever I may need to manipulate it (a deposit / withdrawal system, for example). Is it possible?

Comment: The reactive way to do calculations with userBalance would be to use RxJS operators like map (and combineLatest if you need values from multiple Observables). The simplest way to do this if you're not experienced with RxJS would be to have a variable in your component class that you set inside the subscribe function. `this.userName.subscribe(name=>this.userNameValue = name)`

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel W Strimpel mentioned, the variables you are using are indeed observables and the async pipe is taking care of the subscription and showing displaying the value.
If you need the value of those you can go about in either of these two ways.

1. Have a different variable inside userName subscription as Benjamin Kindle suggested.

   this.userName.subscribe(name=>this.userNameValue = name)
2. Access the value of it directly from the observable

   this.userName.value

Hope that helps!